# System-level, compiled, modern C/C++ replacement

Tags: software-development

I would like recommendations for a modern programming language for system-level developing. By system-level I mean for developing a kernel from scratch, drivers, embedded firmware, boot-loaders, etc. I am only interested in new, modern languages that attempt to be a better C/C++. Must be a compiled language, and run on Linux and Windows. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the best place is for this question. I understand how this might be off-topic here, but sites like Stack Overflow tend to discourage recommendation questions. In any case, the other major choice in this problem space besides Rust is [D](http://dlang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

---

### The Rust Programming Language

---

Check out Rust. It has similar syntax to C++, and is meant to modernize the semantics in an attempt to improve speed and prevent software crashes. Not only that, there's a great tutorial on system-level coding!

As the [official site tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial.html) describes it:

> "Rust is a programming language with a focus on type safety, memory
>   safety, concurrency and performance. It is intended for writing
>   large-scale, high-performance software that is free from several
>   classes of common errors. Rust has a sophisticated memory model that
>   encourages efficient data structures and safe concurrency patterns,
>   forbidding invalid memory accesses that would otherwise cause
>   segmentation faults. It is statically typed and compiled ahead of
>   time."

To get you started, [here is a quick "30 minute" introduction.](http://words.steveklabnik.com/a-30-minute-introduction-to-rust)

[And here is the link to the tutorial on booting into your RUST code.](http://blog.theincredibleholk.org/blog/2013/11/18/booting-to-rust/)

[Rust's Official Site](http://www.rust-lang.org/)

*Note: system level design is NOT simple and I'd recommend getting a book and taking a course on it, after working yourself up to that level of skill. That said, messing with system level is a great way to learn, just don't be too disappointed if you find yourself hitting a wall based on knowledge - it is a great way to learn what you don't know! (Also, computer hardware devices are much less documented / standardized then one would expect.)*

Comment: Can you actually program an OS with Rust?